# Add trend line to longitudinal data line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data-visualization

How can I add a trend line that represents the average values for the groups in red and black? I have tried `geom_line()` and `geom_smooth()` and haven't gotten it to work.

[image: Line graph of values over time]

Here is the code I used to make this graph:

```
ggplot(data = long_data, aes(x = day, y = val, group = ID, colour = outcome)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = as.factor(outcome), linetype = as.factor(outcome)), size = 0.7) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("longdash", "solid")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) + theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "", panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + 
  labs(x = "day", y = var, colour = "outcome ") +
  xlim(0, 25) + 
  ggtitle(var) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ylim(0,100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grouping variable is `ID`, that's what `geom_smooth` will inherit.

Try specifying your desired grouping variable `outcome` by using `geom_smooth(aes(group = outcome))`